# How to change retrofit @GET programatically

Tags: retrofit2

I have a app where I use youtube api and make a get request using retrofit, now I want to get a list of videos for a specific keyword, but for that I have to use a different get req everytime so how can I change the get request programatically

Code for calling API

```
private fun getVideosList() {
    val videos = RetrofitInstance.youtubeapi.getYoutubeVideos()
    videos.enqueue(object : Callback<YoutubeAPIData?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<YoutubeAPIData?>, response: Response<YoutubeAPIData?>) {
            val videosList = response.body()?.items
            if (videosList != null) {
                for(video in videosList) {
                Log.d("title", video.snippet.title)
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<YoutubeAPIData?>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Unable to fetch results!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d("APIError",t.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Retrofit Instance

```
object RetrofitInstance {
const val BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/"
private val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
val youtubeapi: YoutubeListApi by lazy {
    retrofit.create(YoutubeListApi::class.java)
}}
```

Code for API interface

```
interface YoutubeListApi {
@GET("search?part=snippet&q=eminem&key=*my_key*")
fun getYoutubeVideos(): Call<YoutubeAPIData>}
```

Now what I want is to change the @GET("search?part=snippet&q=eminem&key=*my_key*") in the api interface so that if the keyword is eminem it should be search?part=snippet&q=eminem&key=*my_key*
and if keyword is dog it should be search?part=snippet&q=dogkey=*my_key*

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`@Query`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html) from retrofit?

You could redefine your interface to:

```
interface YoutubeListApi {
  @GET("search")
  fun getYoutubeVideos(
     @Query("part") part: String,
     @Query("q") query: String,
     @Query("key") key: String,
  ): Call<YoutubeAPIData>
}
```

and then you can call it like `getYoutubeVideos("snippets", "eminem", "your key")` or `getYoutubeVideos("snippets", "dog", "your key")`.

I think you can even hardcode some values in the URL if you want, but honestly I think you can just use kotlin default values:

```
interface YoutubeListApi {
  @GET("search")
  fun getYoutubeVideos(
     @Query("q") query: String,
     @Query("part") part: String = "snippet",
     @Query("key") key: String = "your key",
  ): Call<YoutubeAPIData>
}
```

and just pass the query `getYoutubeVideos("eminem")`. I haven't double checked this, but I think it could work.